# Search other website content in Main Sharepoint page

Tags: sharepoint-server, search, 2016, search-results

I work on SharePoint Server 2016 On-premises version. Is it possible to search other website content from the main SharePoint site. The other website can be both SharePoint and non-SharePoint websites.

For example:

1. There is a website called abc.com and it has several documents, etc.
2. Now, from my SharePoint page using search, can I get that website content inside my SharePoint page?
3. If yes, please give a me walk around about the workflow and methods to approach the same.

Comment: The SharePoint service would need to have permissions to the content you want to index. If it doesn't, you're SOL. From what you've described, you're wanting to index external content...and SharePoint Search doesn't provide that. You'll need to use something like Google Search API and embed that into your page.

Answer (score 3):

Whether you want to create a content source separately for external web site?

Please create a new Content Source and select the type “Web sites” to be crawled and enter the start address, then start a Full crawl.

More steps refer to the article:

https://mohitvash.wordpress.com/2012/03/07/configure-external-site-as-content-sources-in-sharepoint-search/